# A reader method that returns the value of an instance variable and then resets it to nil

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorter (and cleaner) way to write the following reader method:

```
class Foo
  attr_writer :bar

  def bar
    return_value = @bar
    self.bar = nil
    return_value
  end
end
```

Here's some output on the console to show what it does:

```
>> foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x1010e9cf8>
>> foo.bar
=> nil
>> foo.bar = "ok"
=> "ok"
>> foo.bar
=> "ok"
>> foo.bar
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def bar
    @bar
  ensure
    @bar = nil
  end
```

This can be a one-liner, if you want:

```
  def bar
    @bar ensure @bar = nil
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def bar
   @bar, rv = nil, @bar
   rv
 end
```

or

```
 def bar
   (@bar, rv = nil, @bar)[1]
 end
```

Comment: Definitely less verbose!

My only (minor) criticism would be that we're still juggling the return value via a second variable in the method. Seems there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: @rampion, genius! I totally ignored parallel assignment as an option! I'm glad I stayed tuned in on this to see your answer :)

Comment: @smotchkkiss: You should see Wayne Conrad's - it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. Looks quite short and clean already to me!

Comment: Was imagining there could be a one-liner solution. I am definitely nit-picking!

Comment: It's an interesting question and I would love to be proved wrong! Am still thinking about it now...

Answer (score 0):

Less clever, but perhaps more clear:

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end

  def bar
    @bar.pop
  end

  def bar= (obj)
    @bar[0] = obj
  end

end
```

Comment: I would actually characterize it differently: more clever, but perhaps less clear.